# join Query on attribute of association table

Tags: sql, database

Table 1: `Student`

```
id (PK)
name
```

Table 2: `Course

```
id (PK)
name
```

Table 3: `StudentCourse` (association between student and course)

```
student_id
course_id
grade
PK(student_id, course_id)
```

What will be the SQL query to find names of students and courses where the student received 'F' grade for every course taken by that student?

Comment: quatro-pro ? microsoft works style sheet ? or access mdb ?.... what DATABASE ?

Comment: Do you mean the students that got 'F' in all his/her courses to display any rows at all for that student, or do you mean that only the 'F' grade courses should be shown for students who has got other grades in other courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct ss.student_id,NAME  from StudentCourse  ss JOIN  students ON ss.student_id = students.id  where not exists
(
select course_id from StudentCourse  where  student_id = ss.student_id and grade<>'f'
)
```